# Finding method through reflection and return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, reflection

After having worked with reflection some and managed to get some data back from GetMethods I've finally hit a wall. I've tried to find any sources on this, but to no avail.

Basically I'm creating a RESTFUL Api in ASP.NET (MVC webapi) and using reflection to find the correct method of a DataComponent class that contains hundreds of views / stored procedures. I've gotten past the basic hurdles, but now when I'm finally attempting to use a parameter to find a specific SQL-view I seem to be getting an error:

> Ambiguous match found.

I'm assuming this is because I'm attempting to find a single method through

```
MethodInfo theMethod = myType.GetMethod(toCheck);
```

*But the result is two different methods*.

According to my manager it's due to the fact that we are using two different views that return two different DataTypes (one a DataReader, the other a DataSet).

What I want to ask the **HIVEMIND** is how I can narrow down these two results to a single result either with the help of manually checking for the resulting returntype being DataSet or any other way?

**Follow-up issue:**

I seem to be unable to put the results in a DataSet as the .Invoke method expects an **Object**. I've attempted to set the return to an Object and then casting the object to a DataSet too...

```
Type myType = (typeof(myClass));
            MethodInfo[] arrayToCheck = myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            Object result = new Object();
            foreach (MethodInfo mi in arrayToCheck)
            {
                if (mi.Name.Equals(param) && mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet))
                {
                    result = mi.Invoke(mi, arr);
                }
            }
DataSet ds = (DataSet)result; // Error here
```

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataSet'.

**Continuation of issue:**

Attempted to implement the solution provided by the answer

```
 String[] arr = {"", conStr, ""};
            var myType = (typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC));


            var method = myType.GetMethods(param, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Single(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
            var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            var result = method.Invoke(subject, arr);


            DataSet ds = (DataSet)result;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as intended.

The line

```
  var method = myType.GetMethods (param, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) .Single(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
```

Throws the error

> Unkown method GetMethods(string, System.Reflection.BindingFlags) of
>   System.Type

And

```
mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
```

Throws this error:

> Unkown type of variable mi

Thanks

Comment: call `GetMethods`, loop, checking `.Name` and  `.ReturnType` ?

Comment: Combine @MarcGravells approach with LINQs `Single` method and you will get a nice one-liner.

Comment: Both great comments and I've implemented a loop that does find the view. Now, however, I've managed to find myself in another situation. I can't seem to neither cast the object that I put the results of the view in to a DataSet nor am I allowed to put the results straight in a DataSet. See edit.

Comment: `MethodInfo.Invoke` always returns `object`, you have to cast the result explicitly. Can you provide the error messages you get?

Comment: Added in the edit. :)

Comment: When you expect a DataSet object the line before the loop should read: `DataSet result = null` and then you assign the explicitly casted result value of the invoke call into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your follow-up issue, you need to create an object of the specific type you're calling the method on. For types that have default (no-parameter) constructors, you can do this:

```
        Object result = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

So your overall code could look like this:

```
var myType = typeof(myClass);


var method = myType
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    .Single(mi => mi.Name == param && mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
var result = method.Invoke(subject, arr);


Dataset ds = (DataSet)result ;
```

Comment: So I seem to have found some issues with this. I'll update the question further. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @geostocker: Sorry, `GetMethods()` doesn't take a name. Try checking the name as part of the `Single()` criteria.

Comment: Getting a targetparametercountexception parameter count mismatch error at the method.Invoke(subject, arr); line now. Not really sure how to handle that. The fetch should work fine as it uses the same parameters in a different module (DataSet ds = jdc.FETCHvw_WorksiteEntry("", conStr, "");)