# Reflection to find method through name and returntype

Tags: c#, rest, reflection

I previously had an issue with using reflection that you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124868/finding-method-through-reflection-and-return-type).

After having received an answer to the question and attempted to implement it to my project I seem to have hit yet another wall.

Basically I have this code:

```
 String[] arr = {"", conStr, ""};
            var myType = (typeof(JaberoDC.JaberoDC.JaberoDC));


            var method = myType.GetMethods(param, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Single(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
            var subject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
            var result = method.Invoke(subject, arr);


            DataSet ds = (DataSet)result;
```

Where *param* is a ***String***.

However, it doesn't seem to work as intended.

The line

```
  var method = myType.GetMethods (param, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) .Single(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
```

Throws the error

> Unkown method GetMethods(string, System.Reflection.BindingFlags) of
>   System.Type

And

```
mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet));
```

Throws this error:

> Unkown type of variable mi

Could anyone help me with the correct initialization of my ***method*** variable. I've looked around on Google to see if I could possibly find something to at least point me in the right direction. My previous code (again, see the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124868/finding-method-through-reflection-and-return-type)) compiled and ran, but threw an **ambiguous match found** error.

**EDIT:**

Changed my code to be more like the answer below. However I'm getting an error while debugging it:

> targetparametercountexception parameter count mismatch

That is happening on this line:

```
var result = method.Invoke(subject, arr);
```

From reading about reflection online it seems like you should be passing in an array of parameters that the method you invoke requires (in my case the array). In a different class I use this (which works absolutely fine; I'm attempting to invoke the **exact same method**):

```
DataSet ds = jdc.FETCHvw_WorksiteEntry("", conStr, "");
```

**End of EDIT1.**

Comment: where does `param` come from in your code? it is not shown anywhere in your example currently

Comment: Can you show the method that you're trying to call through reflection ?

Comment: I can't find an overload of Type.GetMethods that receives two arguments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @m1o2 my thought exactly. That's why I thought I'd turn to SO to see if I had either made a shit research or if the person who answered had.

Comment: @user3185569 The class I'm using (jaberodc) is a datacomponent that holds a BUNCH of classes. That's why I'm using param to find the correct method and the returntype to find the correct method with correct returntype. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran Added a reference to param (it's a string parameter, method name)

Comment: There is no overload that takes the arguments you specified. Just use an overload that exists and then filter the results as needed with `Single()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you're attempting, but I don't think it's quite what you want.

```
var method = myType.GetMethods(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
    .Single(mi => 
        mi.ReturnType == typeof(DataSet) 
        && string.Equals(mi.Name, param, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This gets you a method and you know that it returns a `DataSet`, but there's no guarantee that you can invoke it with the argument(s) you have.

This would be better:

```
    var method = myType.GetMethod(param, 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly,
        null, new Type[] {typeof (string)}, null);
```

Where the array `{typeof(string)}` is an array of the parameter types the method receives. That way you're looking for exactly the method you want, not just one with the correct return type.

(I wasn't clear on what the arguments for the method are. If it's two strings then that would be `new Type[] {typeof (string), typeof(string)}`. If it's an array of strings then `new Type[] {typeof (string[])}`.

Comment: That looks great. However using that I seem to get an error in the results.
I'll add an edit to explain it as best as I can.